# How To set Cookie To expire when tab is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to create a session cookie for my media player [here](https://codepen.io/FoxyPlays9978/pen/XQypma) in order to track usage and other things the code and the code snippet below isn't creating it at all, (by the way, i'm using one script to create multiple cookies using parameters and want to keep it like that to prevent lengthily scripts)

I've tried a lot of the answers provided in the website already but they don't work, they just result in the same problem

```
//script to create the cookies
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
//for the cookie that makes the name, not part of the question
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
// also for the name
function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Welcome back " + user
  } else {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Please enter your name in The prompt at the top of your screen!";
     user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
     }
  }
}
window.onload = checkCookie()
//for the session
window.onload = createsession()

function createsession(length){
    var sessionnumber = Random rand = new Random();

long drand = (long)(rand.nextDouble()*10000000000L);
    setCookie("session", sessionnumber);
};
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
};
```

what I want is for the script to create a cookie that expires at end of the browser session, while being able to keep the other scripts the same to allow me to create multiple cookies without making duplicates of those processing scripts

Comment: at the start of the session expire the cookie.  Actually, why do you want to delete the cookie? It will be overwritten when you start a new session

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow. Can you confirm that the cookies are being created? I also do not see your attempts to expire the cookie when you unload the document. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DCR, the reason I want them to be deleted is so the app can track if the users still active but, now that I think about it, I don't want the cookie to be deleted, but now I want it to be deleted when the user is inactive for an amount of time (inactive without music playing)

Comment: @Twisty usually, it expires when the browser is closed if I don't set an expiration date. that usually works for me, I don't know why it's not working now. >:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/toxjLmd8/10/

I added a few things to increase info in console. When I inspect the page and view Storage I can see `session` cookie and `username` cookie. If I refresh, I am prompted to enter name again. So it seems to be working as expected.

```
$(function() {
  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    if (exdays == undefined) {
      exdays = 1;
    }
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    console.log("Set Cookie: " + cname + "=" + cvalue, expires);
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }

  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
      $("#display").html("Welcome back " + user);
    } else {
      $("#display").html("Welcome, please enter your name.");
      user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
      if (user != "" && user != null) {
        setCookie("username", user, 30);
      }
    }
  }

  function newSession() {
    var sessionnumber = Math.random() * 10000000000.0;
    console.log("New Session: " + sessionnumber);
    setCookie("session", sessionnumber, 0.0125);
  }

  function checkSession() {
    if (getCookie("session") == false) {
      newSession();
    }
    console.log("Current Session: " + getCookie("session"));
  }

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.log("Closing - Expire 'username' Cookie");
    setCookie("username", "", 0);
  };

  window.onload = checkCookie();
  window.onload = checkSession();
});
```

Setting a past date or current date and time should have the browser expire the cookie right away and drop it. Setting a cookie with no expiration date can have unexpected results from different browsers. If the date is not set it should expire at the end of the session (the expected behavior) yet the browser may see that it has already expired (still good) or will never expire (really not good). Not all browsers are written the same.

Also if `onbeforeunload` callback is not triggered, the cookie is not expired but would remain active for 30 days per `checkCookie()`. You could set the cookie to expire in 20 min (`0.0125` days). This is how sessions are handled on the server-side. If the socket closes and the session is idle for 20 min (the default for Session Idle Timeout), the session data is dropped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this just now and it totally works, this the best solution that's I've tried. Thanks  :-)

Comment: @ZacharyCross great! I hope you will mark it and upvote it as the answer.